# Modify the old row to NULL in case of duplicate field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, database-trigger

I am trying to modify the row that has the same value that I am inserting in case of a duplicate.

I'm trying to find an equivalence to this to work with Mysql, basically I should do the following:

Pseudocode (Not works because update the same table as the trigger):

```
CREATE TRIGGER users_insert_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON Users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE Users
    SET token = NULL
    WHERE token = NEW.token;
END;
```

Table Users before the Insert:

```
id, name, password, token
1, Bob, 1234, token1
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO Users (name, password, token) VALUES ('Alice', '1234', 'token1')
```

Table users the insert:

```
id, name, password, token
1, Bob, 1234, NULL
2, Alice, 1234, token1.
```

Could it be done in some way? Thank you very much!

Comment: I can't imagine a real life scenario where you would want this behavior.  Why should Bob's token get nulled out just because someone else tried to insert the same value?  MySQL has an `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` clause which can (and here probably should) be used to change the token value of Alice, who is trying to usurp someone else's token value.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Let's suppose that the "token" is a mobile that both Alice and Bob use. The mobile can not have both at the same time. So when Alice creates or updates, she removes Bob's mobile. The only solution I have found for now is to create a UsersToken table and make an "INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE" of the token. But I just do not like to have to separate it into two tables, is there any solution for a single table and to be able to set the value of Alice to NULL?

Comment: You should edit your question and put this business logic there.  This is a far departure from your OP.